# PHP AES-256-CBC encrypted data is different from JAVA AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I have a java code working perfectly

```
public static String encrypt(String message, String sercretKey)
    {
        String base64EncryptedString = "";
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(sercretKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
            byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
            byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 16);
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
            javax.crypto.Cipher cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParameterSpec);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
            byte[] buf = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
            byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(buf);
            base64EncryptedString = new String(base64Bytes);
        return base64EncryptedString;
    }
```

I have tried using below code to recreate this above code in PHP

```
function encryptTest($sSecretKey,$sValue)
        {
            $key = hash('sha256', $sSecretKey,false);
            $key = utf8_encode($key);
            $key = substr($key, 0, 24);
            $iv = substr($key, 0, 16);
            $data = $sValue;
            $outEnc = openssl_encrypt($data, "AES-256-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
            
            return base64_encode($outEnc);
        }
```

But showing different results. What I have missed.

(Same types of questions are available in StackOverflow, but pointing my issues)

Comment: $key = substr($key, 0, 32) shoud this be  $key = substr($key, 0, 24)?

Comment: tried that too.. but encrypted values are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the following issues:

- In the PHP code, the key is currently returned hex encoded. Instead, it must be returned as bytes string. To do this, the third parameter in `hash()` must be switched from `false` to `true`.
- In the Java code a 192 bits key is used, i.e. AES-192. Accordingly, in the PHP code `"AES-192-CBC"` must be applied (and not `"AES-256-CBC"`).
- The `utf8_encode()` call in the PHP code is to be removed, as this corrupts the key.

With these changes, both codes provide the same ciphertext.

Security:
Using SHA256 as key derivation is insecure. Instead apply a dedicated algorithm like Argon2 or PBKDF2. Also, using the key (or a part of it) as IV is insecure as it results in the reuse of key/IV pairs. Instead, a randomly generated IV should be applied for each encryption.

Comment: Actually I have ended up to this solution, and it is worked.